# append dataframe in specific cell

Tags: mysql, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I am trying to grab data from a mysql database and put it in an excel template ( with macro's).
The template has mutiple sheets.I want to put the data in a specific sheet and specific cell ( B2 ) since the sheet already contains data.
The code i am using is:

```
wb= openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/Olav/Desktop/Xenos/Nieuw.xlsx')
ws = wb['Dump Pickloc - del. web']

picklocaties = "SELECT Artikelnummer, Locatie,PICKZONE FROM picklocaties WHERE PICKZONE in ('BASIS','HL')"
df = pd.read_sql(sql=picklocaties, con=mydb)

rows = dataframe_to_rows(df)

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False):
    ws.append(r)
```

I tryed using to_excel but that just deletes everything.

The template in which i am putting the data looks like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re7Lm.jpg).
It would be great if this code would work but it does not have that option:
`for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False, startrow=1, startcol=1):`
    `ws.append(r)` \

Woah i'm half way there, woah living on prayer.
This codes gets me halfway. I get the columns now where i want without messing up the rest. But for some reason the rest of the data is not shown.

```
for col, text in enumerate(df, start=2):
    ws.cell(column=col,row=2, value=text)
```

Comment: this? https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_positioning.html

Comment: I tryed this and this deletes all the other sheets and it deletes the existing text which is in the sheet.